# iOS XCode: How to create different project settings for the same application

Tags: ios, xcode6, app-store-connect

Our iOS mobile app is used by different organisations. Some may belong to a different Development Team and therefore have their own provisioning profiles. Some organisations may wish to change the name of the app or even change the icon. So whenever I build an IPA I have to perform the following changes to the project settings:

1. Go to the General tab and update the Bundle Identifier and Team.
2. Then go to Build Settings/Code Signing and change the Code Signing Identity and Provisioning Profile names.

My question is: is it possible to create custom configurations so that I could set the project configuration settings for each organisation and then easily switch between them without having to manually update details in points 1 & 2 every time I did an archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using targets might help you, go to your project settings, open up the project panel on the left. right click on your target, then click duplicate, now you can edit the necessary settings.
[image]

click the button next to start / stop to swap between your targets when running.

Comment: Thanks @Fonix - When I click on Add Target I am asked to choose a template for the new target. Does it matter what I choose here? All I'm interested in are build settings.

Comment: ye doesnt matter initially, it sort of creates another project for you within your project, you just need to make the new files inside this new target use the ones from your old target. let me update my answer quick with some more info

Comment: oh actually im being silly, you can duplicate your old target, hold on

Comment: wow, if you could duplicate the original target it would be fantastic!

Comment: I found the way to duplicate. Just right-click the target and choose Duplicate. Absolutely brilliant. Thank you so much.

Comment: yeah i just updated the answer to reflect that, no problem :)